# Activity back tracking in Activity stack - Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having two activities, Activity A and activity B.

Activity A starts activity B.

So, the activity stack after some interactions will look like A -> B -> A -> B.

The problem:
I need to go the first activity A in the stack from activity B (last B in the stack). I am using FLAG_CLEAR_TOP as well as Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for achieving the same.

Right now, the activity A (stack pos 3) will be shown from activity B, but when I press back button, the activity B will be shown again (since activity B (stack pos 2) is already there in the stack).

How do I overcome this issue?

PS: I tried using launchMode singleInstance and singleTask for activities A and B, but that solution doesn't work for my app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you go from the first Activity B to the second activity A?

Comment: I am navigating to the second activity A using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: Dropping FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK might already solve your problem, but I'm not sure. Why don't you just call `finish` in the first Activity B to leave that activity? Then you automatically go back to A, which is your first A

Comment: Do you specify activity B as parent of activity A in manifest ? this can be a cause of your problem

Comment: @AntonMalmygin. No, I haven't specified B as the parent activity of A in the manifest.

Comment: You do not need special launch modes, they won't help and you will make more problems. Also, you do not need `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. It is being ignored anyway because you haven't set `taskAffinity`, so you aren't ending up with multiple tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Add `finish ();` after switching activites like

```
Intent intent = new Intent (activity_a.this, activity_b.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid creating multiple instances of activities if possible. Android isn't designed to allow you to identify (and return to) a specific instance of an `Activity` in the stack, if you have multiple instances of the same `Activity` in the stack.

Depending on your application, there are different ways to solve the problem.

One way that may work for you is to use `<activity-alias>`, which allows you to reuse an existing `Activity` implementation by another name.

Another way would be to create another `Activity` class, that just inherits from the original, so that you have 2 classes with exactly the same code, but with different names.

The best way is to rearchitect your application so that you only ever have one instance of each `Activity` alive at any given time. You can do this by rearranging the task stack using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`.